# Need driver for AMD R7 260/265 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, amd-graphics, lts

My current system settings say I have driver for Intel® Haswell Mobile

I have i5 processor Intel® Core™ i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4 
and AMD R7 260 GPU

```
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] [1002:6900]
```

I need to install AMD graphics card driver for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
I tried AMDGPU. Seems it is not supported , system goes in black screen loop mode and never comes out unless I uninstall it.

fglrx is depreceated.

In some blogs i read one can try radeon driver?

Where can i get the radeon driver from.

Website for .deb or commands are appreciated!

Comment: It should be running with the radeon driver already, run `lscpi -nnkd 1002:6900`

Comment: It looked like I dont see good graphics or good video performance prateek@prateek-Inspiron-5547:~$ lspci -nnkd 1002:6900
03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] [1002:6900]
 Subsystem: Dell Radeon R7 M260/M265 [1028:0640]
 Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
 Kernel modules: amdgpu